# Return a string from a C# method to a C++ function in an output argument

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling, com-interop, variant

I am invoking a C# method from a C++ function.

The C# method should do the following:

- Allocate a `BSTR` and return it to the C++ function in an output argument
- Return an `HRESULT` to the C++ function through the stack (by return-value)

---

I have implemented the C# method as follows:

```
int Method(out IntPtr output)
{
    int status = 0;
    ...
    output = Marshal.StringToBSTR(someString);
    ...
    return status;
}
```

---

**Questions:**

- What variant-type should I use in C++, which corresponds the `out IntPtr` type in C#?
- Is there some other type in C# that I should use instead, in order to return the `BSTR`?
- If yes, then what C# type is it, and what is the corresponding C++ variant-type?

I have tried several variant types listed [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa908601.aspx), but none of them seemed to work.

Comment: Is the C++ code use C# DLL as a COM component? or you're writing C++/CLI?

Comment: @Matt: First option.

Answer (score 0):

You're using [COM Callable Wrapper](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f07c8z1c(v=vs.110).aspx), for your questions:

1. C# `out IntPtr` is mapped to `void**` in [COM data types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sak564ww(v=vs.100).aspx).
2. By default, the C# string type is marshaled as BSTR type in COM, please check [Default Marshaling for Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9ts558h(v=vs.100).aspx), so you can just use string in C#
3. The variant type for BSTR is VT_BSTR, but if you're only dealing with strings, you could just BSTR, you don't need to use variant types.

Comment: But I'm not passing a `BSTR` to the C# method. I am passing `BSTR*`, into which the C# method should write the address of a newly-allocated `BSTR`. So I cannot use `VT_BSTR` for that purpose.

Comment: but you're passing Intptr out, it becomes void** .

Comment: On the C# side, I'm expecting `out IntPtr` (unless you have a better suggestion). What `VT` should I use on the C++ side when I invoke this method?

Comment: why you want pass BSTR type for C# to COM?

Comment: I need the C# method to allocate some string with information and return it to me. That's why I want to pass a **`BSTR*`** to it. By the way, that link you mention on your second bullet indicates that the corresponding C# type for `BSTR*` is `System.String`. That's good, I like it. But I assume that I should declare `out String` in the C# method, right? And perhaps I should use `VT_BSTR | VT_BYREF`? It's a shame that the table in the link doesn't have a `VT` column.